# How to set up a custom shared namespace and use in my project in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, compilation, namespaces, qooxdoo

I have a project and I need to create a shared namespace.

I have my shared namespace like this: c:\namespaces\test

Here I have files like a.js

How do I compile my project in order to include all the files in the test namespace?
thanks

Comment: Cross-post from the qooxdoo mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the mailing list: http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-up-a-custom-shared-namespace-and-use-in-my-project-in-Qooxdoo-td7365092.html;cid=1345706918184-716

You don't want to share a namespace, you want to share code. You can share 
code across projects, independent of a common namespace.

For the shared code, just create a separate qooxdoo application, like you 
would for a new project (e.g. with 'create-application.py -n test'). Add 
a.js to the usual source path, e.g. test/source/class/a.js.

Then, in your main project add the new library 'test' to the config.json. 
E.g. in the "jobs" section add

"libraries" : { 
  "library" : [ 
     { "manifest" : "path/to/test/Manifest.json" } 
   ] 
}

Now you can use classes from the 'test' namespace like other qooxdoo 
classes in the application code:

var a = new test.a();